# Can I create a folder using Javascript program

Tags: javascript

Can I create a folder using Java script program like

```
  var fso, fldr;
  fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  fldr = fso.CreateFolder("C:\\MyTest");
```

Comment: when I call ActiveXobject is says it is not defined............is there anything code in core javascript which can do the same. please suggest me.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/help/genuine/ie-activex

Comment: is there anything alternative to activeXObject for other browsers

Comment: No, no there are alternatives.

Comment: No because it opens up a huge security problem. For example, I could create folders and install any virus/trojan/worm etc that I like.

Comment: no you can do that in client side code

Answer (score 0):

ActiveXObject is only available within Internet Explorer, also the correct permissions must be set before this is possible.

More info:

http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Javascript-FSO-CreateFolder-Method.aspx

Comment: if i need in other browsers . how can i do it. can you suggest me.

Comment: If your building a moblie app, you can use cordova/phonegap to allow for native file system operations using javascript, for desktop browsers you have to use each browsers custom APIs, like firefox has web api and file IO https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API

Comment: what do you want todo with the new folder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create, however it will only run IE browser and you need to perform [IE - setting](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/help/genuine/ie-activex) too.

```
var folder = "C:\\testing";
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
if (!fso.FolderExists(folder)) {
    fso.CreateFolder(folder);
}
fso=null;
```

Comment: if I need through firefox, opera , mozila, then what I have to do.

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with other Browsers! And that's good!